# camera_calibration - override enough data check

Tags: ros, calibration, frames, stereo, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'd like to calibrate a stereo rig with the camera_calibration stereo node. I have a set of pre-recorded images that I publish using a simple ad-hoc player node and with some datasets it works pretty well. I followed [stereo tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) and *if* the number of images in my sequence is enough no problem arises. The problem is when I do not have *enough frames* and the calibrate button never lights.

Do you know how I can override the *good enough* check?

Thank you,
Augusto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222374/camera_calibration---override-enough-data-check/) by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 430 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there is a magic number of 40:

```
self.goodenough = (len(self.db) >= 40) or all([p == 1.0 for p in progress])
```

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py#L311

Change it to zero or whatever you like (clone the the image_pipeline pipeline into your `catkin_ws` and `catkin_make` it, if devel or install is sourced it should take precedence over the unmodified image_pipeline elsewhere on your system when you rosrun/launch it).

You could also probably fake it by send the same images repeatedly until 40 is reached.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2015-12-14**:
Thanks, it works like a charm ;-)